# Using type handler in where clause in MyBatis

Tags: mybatis

Can I use type handler in where clause when writing dynamic query in MyBatis?

I have to convert the Boolean value to char. the false will be converted to "N" and true to "Y". As the value store in the column are either Y or N

Answer (score 3):

Yes , you can use MyBatis typehandlers

```
public class YesNoBooleanTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<Boolean> {

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Boolean parameter, JdbcType jdbcType)
            throws SQLException {
        ps.setString(i, convert(parameter));
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName)
            throws SQLException {
        return convert(rs.getString(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex)
            throws SQLException {
        return convert(rs.getString(columnIndex));
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex)
            throws SQLException {
        return convert(cs.getString(columnIndex));
    }

    private String convert(Boolean b) {
        return b ? "Y" : "N";
    }

    private Boolean convert(String s) {
        return s.equals("Y");
    }

}
```

Mapper.xml where clause:

```
... WHERE your_bool = #{yourBool,typeHandler=YesNoBooleanTypeHandler} ...
```