# MyBatis: Map String to boolean

Tags: java, mybatis

I have booleans inserted in my database as Y/N. When I try to map the result to a boolean java type, it always set it to a false in any case in my pojo.

Is there any way to map String to boolean? Here's my code:

```
<resultMap id="getFlag" type="MyPojo">
    <result property="myFlag" column="MY_FLAG"/>
</resultMap>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure hibernate (using JPA) to store Y/N for type Boolean instead of 0/1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154833/configure-hibernate-using-jpa-to-store-y-n-for-type-boolean-instead-of-0-1)

Comment: You can convert `Y/N` to `boolean` in your query sql.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need is a typeHandler for you Y/N Boolean type:
([more explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338861/using-type-handler-in-where-clause-in-mybatis))
Actual Handler:

```
public class YesNoBooleanTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<Boolean> {

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Boolean parameter, JdbcType jdbcType)
            throws SQLException {
        ps.setString(i, convert(parameter));
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName)
            throws SQLException {
        return convert(rs.getString(columnName));
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex)
            throws SQLException {
        return convert(rs.getString(columnIndex));
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex)
            throws SQLException {
        return convert(cs.getString(columnIndex));
    }

    private String convert(Boolean b) {
        return b ? "Y" : "N";
    }

    private Boolean convert(String s) {
        return s.equals("Y");
    }

}
```

Your usage:

```
<result property="myFlag" column="MY_FLAG" javaType="java.lang.Boolean" jdbcType="VARCHAR" typeHandler="com.foo.bar.YesNoBooleanTypeHandler" />
```

Comment: Rememember to register your Y/N TypeHandler upon creating your SqlSessionFactoryBean like this: factory.setTypeAliases(new Class[]{YesNoBooleanTypeHandler.class}). You must already configure your SqlSesionFactory in your applicationContext.xml [if using Spring XML] or Spring Config @Configuration [if using java annotations].

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to look at implementing a custom TypeHandler.
http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers.